# Range Object: Rows.EntireRow vs EntireRow

Tags: excel, vba

Is it any difference between the two codes below?

```
Code 1:
...
'rg1 is some Range Object
dim rg2 as Range
set rg2 = rg1.Rows.EntireRow
...
Code 2:
...
'rg1 is some Range Object
dim rg2 as Range
set rg2 = rg1.EntireRow
...
```

Comment: In that context, no any difference between the returned ranges. `EntireRow` returns the whole rows range.  `rg1.rows` is a range itself, too. It happens that both of them returns the same final range. For instance. `rg.columns`entireRow` returns the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - you can check it with this code:

```vb
Sub test()
Dim rg1 As Range: Set rg1 = Selection

Dim rg2 As Range
Set rg2 = rg1.Rows.EntireRow

Dim rg3 As Range
Set rg3 = rg1.EntireRow

Debug.Print "rg2: " & rg2.Address, "rg3: " & rg3.Address

End Sub
```

result will be e.g. `rg2: $6:$9    rg3: $6:$9` if `C6:C9` is selected